# If equals error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

So I've been having an issue with this script and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to fix it.

I'm trying to scan a cell range and find the value of "X", which also has to align with the array (which seems to be working) that finds a value in another range of columns that is greater than 7.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim Checks As Variant
Dim RiskName As Variant
Dim Level As Integer
Dim ThreatAgent As Variant
Dim Vulns As Variant

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim impactRange As Range
Dim impactCell As Range
Dim checksRange As Range
Dim checksCell As Range

Me.UsedRange.Offset(17).ClearContents

X = 2
Y = 1

With Sheets("TA & Vul Combinations")
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    Set impactRange = .Range("R3:R50")

    For Each impactCell In impactRange.Cells

        If impactCell.Cells > 7 And Not IsEmpty(impactCell.Cells) Then
            impactCell.Copy
            Sheets("temp").Range("B" & X).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            X = X + 1
        Else

        End If
    Next impactCell

    Set checksRange = .Range("E3:E50")

    For Each checksCell In checksRange.Cells

        If checksCell.Cells("E3") = "X" Then
            checksCell.Copy
            Sheets("temp").Range("C2:AO2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else

            Range("K1") = "You Broke It"
        End If

    Next checksCell

    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

If anyone could give me some tips that would be great

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
If checksCell.Cells("E3") = "X" Then
```

since you are using `Cells` property incorrectly.
`Cells` property only accepts numeric arguments.
**Syntax:** *Cells(rowindex,colindex)*

**Examples:**

```
Cells(1,1) 'refers to Range("A1")
Cells(1) 'refers to Range("A1")
```

However, you can also use letters for `Columns` like this:

```
Cells(1,"A") 'refers to Range("A1")
```

Btw, this will work though.

```
If checksCell.Range("E3") = "X" Then
```

But take note of the implications.
When you use `Range.Range` syntax, what happens is that you use a `Relative Reference` on your first range.

**Example1:**

```
Range("B2").Range("E3").Address
```

will give you `$F$4` because that is the 5th (E) column and 3rd (3) row from `B2`.

**Other Examples:**

```
Range("C1:E10").Range("B2").Address 'refers to $D$2
Range("C1:E10").Range("A1:B3").Address 'refers to $C$1:$D$3
```

Hope this clear things up a bit.
I don't know exactly what you want to achieve in your code, so I will not provide corrections.
I can only tell why you are getting errors.
If you need additional help, revise your question and clear major things up.

Answer (score 0):

Re this line, which is probably the one where your error lies (it's the only `if equals` line in the code block):

```
If checksCell.Cells("E3") = "X" Then
```

I'm pretty certain `checksCell` is *already* a cell from doing a `for each` on the range `checksRange`, so I'm not sure that applying `.Cells("E3")` to it is the right thing to do, or even a *sane* thing to do :-)

I would think the correct way would be:

```
If checksCell.Value = "X" Then
```